# Converting from List to Array

Tags: apex

I wish to convert a list of Strings to an array of strings.

I do:

```
// ccEmails is the list of Strings
String [] emailsAsArray = new String [ccEmails.size()];
Integer i = 0;
for (String singleCCEmail: ccEmails) {
    emailsAsArray[i++] = singleCCEmail;
}
```

This seems a horrible cumbersome way.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you talking Apex? Java? C#? If Apex, there is no such thing as Array. It is all list, even though the syntax looks like array.

Comment: sorry...should have noticed. :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no such thing as array in Apex.

The creators of Apex decided that they would support two different but completely compatible syntax conventions for the same underlying object: List. One *looks* like array, the other looks like List, but they are both List.

I could literally do this:

```
List<String> myStrings = new String[2];

myStrings[0] = 'this'; 
myStrings.set(1,'that');
myStrings.add('the other');

System.debug(myStrings);
```

This (ugly and unreadable as it is) compiles and runs successfully.