# how to convert list<String> to String[]

Tags: apex, batch

I am writing a batch job to send an email to a lead owner's manager. I have `List<String> mgremails` in which I have extracted only the email addresses of the manager.

```
List<User> mgr = [select Manager.email FROM User where Id in :leadOwnerId];

list<string> mgremails = new list<string>();
for(User u : mgr){
    mgremails.add(u.manager.email);
}
```

I now need `String[]` as parameter for the setToAddresses method of the `Messaging` class. How do I do this conversion?

Comment: I believe there are many question related to this one. Anyways, List<String> and String[] are treated as same in Salesforce. You don't need conversion.

Comment: Check this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/is-there-a-difference-between-an-array-and-a-list-in-apex) related to the same topic under discussion and has good detail.

Comment: There is [another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8200/converting-from-list-to-array?rq=1) one with the same question.

Comment: is my syntax correct ? mail.setToAddresses(mgremails);

Comment: Yup, your syntax looks fine to me.

Comment: But my batch job failed and gave the following error : First error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]

Comment: Check the update in the answer below by @Adrian. Make sure you are assigning your **email** object , the email addresses, i.e. `mgremails`.

Answer (score 3):

They're the same. You can pass a `List<String>` instance in where `String[]` is expected, and vice versa.

Here's a simple script you can run in `Execute Anonymous` to prove it:

```
static void doStuff(List<String> input) { system.debug(input); }
static void doOtherStuff(String[] input) { system.debug(input); }

doStuff(new String[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c' });
doOtherStuff(new List<String> { 'x', 'y', 'z' });
```

---

From the comments, make sure you actually call `setToAddresses` on your `SingleEmailMessage` instance:

```
email.setToAddresses(mgrEmails);
```

Comment: Boy! You are following the comments and updating your answer quickly. Whew! :D

Comment: @ngc Never send emails in a loop! You only get 10 invocations.

Comment: @ngc Perhaps you should ask a separate question that is *not* a duplicate as indicated above, and lays out what you have done so far and the verbatim error message. Changing the context via comments isn't great for usability as far as the Stack Exchange format is concerned.